# After messing with DEs, DMs, panel, icon size and greeter are messed up. How can I fix this?

Tags: unity, 16.04, login-screen

[image: desktop unity messed up]

So I was messing with installing Gnome and KDE desktop environments, and ended up deciding not to. When I was finished, I logged out. Upon opening my laptop again, there were several problems.

**Problems**: The greeter / login screen had no area where the password that I had typed would show up. I still was able to type in my password and login to my computer, where I found that all my icons were several times larger than they were supposed to be. And on top of this, the top panel in Unity had gone from being the opaque gray I was comfortable with to a translucent.

I do not know if this problem has to do with compiz, lightdm, unity, or something else.

Comment: have you tried `dconf reset -f /` to reset all settings?

Comment: Hi! I have a suggestion. Instead of adding an update to your own question, I think you should write your solution as an answer and then mark it as your preferred answer. Thus, your question will be marked as solved and people facing the same problem as yours will know that there is a solution for it. I warmly encourage you in doing so as I am myself one of the silent beneficiaries of this website.  I think we should give back what we have received. That's the spirit of open source.  That's Ubuntu's spirit.

Comment: `dconf reset -f /` did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NeverMind. I reinstalled Ubuntu....

Answer (score 0):

You have Unity Tweak Tool select panel tab and check the Transparency level if its value is at zero then try to switch to an another theme and then switch back to ambiance theme and check the result.

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work.